# TLS self-signed certificate for auth URL for Docker

Tags: ssl, go, docker, certificate, openshift-origin

I am trying to log in to the Docker registry you build with the oadm tool. I attempt to log in using a token:

```
# docker login -u $(oc whoami) -e 'xxxx' -p $(oc whoami -t) 172.30.10.52:5000
Error response from daemon: no successful auth challenge for   
https://172.30.10.52:5000/v2/ - errors: [basic auth attempt to 
https://172.30.10.52:5000/v2/ realm "openshift" failed with status: 400 Bad 
Request]
```

Looking in the logs, I can see that the problem is because my instance uses a self-signed certificate:

```
time="2017-01-10T00:58:42.913539516Z" level=error msg="error authorizing context: 
Get https://ld7-zko8s6q-ws:8443/oapi/v1/users/~: x509: 
certificate signed by unknown authority" 
go.version=go1.4.2 http.request.host="172.30.10.52:5000" 
http.request.id=3fa81975-3aa9-44d8-a6a8-c00ad360009c 
http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr="10.1.0.1:49316" 
http.request.uri="/v2/" http.request.useragent="docker/1.10.3 go/go1.6.2 
git-commit/429be27-unsupported kernel/3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64 
os/linux arch/amd64" instance.id=2a23b229-2a0e-4734-83c4-38cb9c8a0e00
```

How can I either get my certificate to be trusted or to turn off TLS verification?

Answer (score 0):

You could *test* an [insecure registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/) by adding

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry myregistrydomain.com:5000"
```

to your  `/etc/default/docker` file or `/etc/sysconfig/docker` file

But it is best to [add your self-signed certificate](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#/using-self-signed-certificates) to `/etc/docker/certs.d/myregistrydomain.com:5000/ca.crt`. And restart your Docker daemon.
That way, it will trust your certificate.

Note that Openshift origin has a [currently open issue 1753](https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/1753) "Need mechanism for registering certs for private docker registries"
See also "[Can not pull image from remote node #6228](https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/6228)" referring to the Openshift official documentation "[Securing and Exposing the Registry](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/registry/securing_and_exposing_registry.html)".